# Separate decimals from main number and multiply

Tags: google-sheets, decimal, google-sheets-formula

I have this number 69,64 (in my country decimals are marked using commas), so I need to have 0,64. I made it using `=MOD(D1;1)`.

But when I multiply 0,64 x 71.800,00 I get 45.800,00 instead of 45.952,00.

Can you tell me why, please?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

```
=MOD(69,64; 1)*71800
```

make sure 71800,00 is number:

[image: 0]

### ______________________________________________________________